# How do I create a workspace with local folder mappings in tfs using C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, tfs

I am trying to automate to get the latest code from TFS server to local path. The initial step for this is to create a workspace in TFS server if not exist already. How will i create the workspace with local folders mapping to the server folders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`VersionControlServer.CreateWorkSpace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138613.aspx) method to create a workspace and set the working folders (use one of the overloads that accepts a [`WorkingFolder[]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138615.aspx). Or update the workspace after initial creation. You can add addtional mappings and cloaks to the workspace at any point in time.

Getting to the `VersionControlServer` and [connecting to TFS using the API is described in this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj883959.aspx).