# Team Foundation : There is no working folder mapping for

Tags: .net, vb.net

```
Dim _versionControlServer As VersionControlServer = tfs.GetService(Of VersionControlServer)()
Dim _workspace As Workspace = _versionControlServer.GetWorkspace(Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())))
```

> `GetWorkspace()` throws Exception : "There is no working folder mapping for .."

(Windows 10, Visual Studio 2012, VB.Net, TeamFoundation server Version 12.0, specific version= true)

Comment: You can [create a workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.createworkspace(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_0) if it doesn't exist.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: The workspace exists. I want to do a GetRequest(). It seems to work in VS2013 without problems?! VS2012 and VS2015 still throws the exception...

Comment: It could just be a path problem.  `Path.GetDirectoryName(Path.GetDirectoryName(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()))` goes up two folders from the current directory, which puts you in the project folder if debugging.  In my example project I'd have to go up three folders to get to the root of the solution, which is more likely where your workspace is mapped.

Answer (score 0):

Check [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682662/how-do-i-create-a-workspace-with-local-folder-mappings-in-tfs-using-c-sharp):

Use the [VersionControlServer.CreateWorkSpace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138613.aspx) method to create a workspace and set the working folders (use one of the overloads that accepts a [WorkingFolder()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb138615.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me in both VS2013 and VS2015.

```
Imports Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client
Imports Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client

Module Module1

    Dim localFolder As String = "C:\TFS\Path\to\source"
    Dim serverFolder As String = "$/Path/to/source"
    Dim tfsUri As Uri = New Uri("https://tfs.yourcompany.com/tfs/YourCollection")
    Dim workspaceName As String = "newWorkspace"

    Function CreateOrMapWorkspace() As Workspace
        REM TfsTeamProjectCollection Is IDisposable so a "using" Is recommended.
        Using ttpc As New TfsTeamProjectCollection(tfsUri)


            Dim vcs As VersionControlServer = ttpc.GetService(Of VersionControlServer)()
            Dim ws As Workspace
            Try

                ws = vcs.GetWorkspace(localFolder)
            Catch

                REM create workspace
                Dim cwp As CreateWorkspaceParameters = New CreateWorkspaceParameters(workspaceName)
                cwp.Folders = Array.CreateInstance(GetType(WorkingFolder), 1)
                cwp.Folders(0) = New WorkingFolder(serverFolder, localFolder)
                ws = vcs.CreateWorkspace(cwp)
            End Try

            Return ws

        End Using
    End Function

    Sub Main()
        CreateOrMapWorkspace()
    End Sub

End Module
```